# How do I center nav items after the navbar got resized by a larger image?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I added a logo to the navbar and it made the navbar a bit larger..
you can replace the img source to any image you want, the effect is the same
I tried to nest the element below in a   `<div class="d-flex align-items-center">`, which I saw on the docs at the flexbox section but has no effect.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav  justify-content-around bg-warning nav-tabs " >
            <img src="logo.png" style="height: 60px;">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link  text-success " href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link text-success" href="#">News</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link text-success" href="#">Items</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a href="#" class=" text-danger nav-link">Affiliate</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added d-flex and align-items-center to the nav class. This will solve your problem. I don't know where you're trying to add this, but it's got to be here for what you want. Because you want to center the elements in ul.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav  justify-content-around bg-warning nav-tabs d-flex align-items-center ">
    <img src="https://www.bidolubaski.com/sites/default/files/u61150/google-logo.jpg" style="height: 60px;">
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link  text-success " href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link text-success" href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link text-success" href="#">Items</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a href="#" class=" text-danger nav-link">Affiliate</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The classes you added solved my problem, thanks a lot! I tried to add them to the div near container-fluid, my logic telling me that if I do that all the elements which will be part of the fluid container will be centered and it got me really frustrated. Cheers mate!